# How to open the current url in chrome to other available browsers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create my first extension which will open the current URL in other/all available browsers. Does anyone have an idea about how to do it? I have already constructed the codes that opens the current url to a new tab/new window:

```
chrome.windows.create({url: newTab, type: "normal"});
```

If it is not possible, does anyone know what language can do it.

Comment: It's likely that a Chrome extension would not have the ability to open arbitrary windows on the host machine. You may want to look into external options (maybe Python, AppleScript, or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, from Chrome extensions you cannot execute other programs.  I did find a simple way around this however.

You need some native application running outside of the browser to accept requests from your browser extension.  I did this over HTTP on an odd-ball port only accessible from localhost.  When a button in my extension is clicked, it fires off an HTTP request to my application, which can do whatever you need it to do.

There is now an API for communicating with native applications from Chrome extensions, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: What application exactly are you talking about? Is is an open source? By the way, thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @user3400081 This would be some application you write.  You need to write the code that does whatever you need to do...

Comment: What I am trying to say, is what IDE should I use to develop the said application that can communicate best in chrome extensions? Can I use java for this? I only have eclipse IDE on my desktop, do I need to use other IDE?

Comment: You can use whatever you want, and certainly whatever IDE you want.  Java wouldn't be my first choice, but to each their own.  You just need something running that can accept HTTP connections, and can do whatever you need it to do.